# Mysql function doesnt work

Tags: mysql

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS shorten;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION shorten(s VARCHAR(255), n INT)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
 BEGIN
 IF ISNULL(s) THEN
   RETURN '';
 ELSE IF n<15 THEN
    RETURN LEFT(s, n);
 ELSE IF CHAR_LENGTH(s) <= n THEN
   RETURN s;
 ELSE
  RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(s, n-10), ' ... ', RIGHT(s, 5));
  END IF;
 END$$
```

The message that I get is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 14 
>   >

Where is teh error..cause I am new to making function in mysql.

**UPDATE :**

It points to an error with some rounded question mark between those lines:

```
ELSE IF n <15 THEN RETURN LEFT( s, n ) ;

ELSE IF CHAR_LENGTH( s ) <= n THEN RETURN s;
```

BTW, I use phpmyadmin

**mysql version is: mysqlnd 5.0.10**

Comment: Have you tried evaluating a shorter version of this to see if you can narrow down where the problem is? There doesn't seem to be a `>` in this version.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are calling `delimiter $$` and then continuing to use `;` as a delimiter.

Comment: @murgatroid99 this is exactly the way to do it, when declaring a procedure, function or trigger.

Comment: @murgatroid99 No, that is correct when inserting functions. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: OK. It's been a while since I've done SQL, so I don't really remember

Comment: True.. I think that the delimiter is designed to end the function and disregards what is inside the function... I get the error on line 14 anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure bt i don't understand why you close if (`END IF;`) two times..?
This may be a probable problem in your code. Please check it.And `ELSE IF` should be without space i.e `ELSEIF`.
The code should be:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS shorten;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION shorten(s VARCHAR(255), n INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
 BEGIN
 IF ISNULL(s) THEN
 RETURN '';
 ELSEIF n<15 THEN
RETURN LEFT(s, n);
 ELSEIF CHAR_LENGTH(s) <= n THEN
 RETURN s;
 ELSE
 RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(s, n-10), ' ... ', RIGHT(s, 5));
  END IF;
 END;$$
 delimiter;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

Comment: the delimiter was not closed properly. that may be a reason. I have updated the code. Could you please check it now.And let me know if it works

Comment: Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.0003 sec ).. However I do  have some error concerning the delimiter

Comment: Why wasnt the delimiter closed properly.. why do you have to close it like this. delimiter;?

Comment: The default delimiter in SQL is ';' symbol that defines end of the query. When we define a delimiter, it takes the code between the delimiters as single query. The last line ie 'delimiter;' tell that the delimiter end here. It is done as we do for any other loop like when we use if we end the code as 'END IF;'. you can read more about delimiters at this link http://buysql.com/mysql/42-na-perevod-chto-takoe-delimiter-v-mysql-i-dlya-chego-on-nuzhen.html

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra `END IF` you need to remove, and replace `ELSE IF` by `ELSEIF`:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS shorten;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION shorten(s VARCHAR(255), n INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
 IF ISNULL(s) THEN
  RETURN '';
 ELSEIF n<15 THEN
  RETURN LEFT(s, n);
 ELSEIF CHAR_LENGTH(s) <= n THEN
  RETURN s;
 ELSE
  RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(s, n-10), ' ... ', RIGHT(s, 5));
 END IF;
END$$
```

The last error Dmitry had was because of an extra semi-colon:

```
WRONG code: delimiter $$; 
GOOD code: delimiter $$
```

Comment: Now I get this with your code: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

Comment: yes, the error reported is on the first ELSE IF. I'll fix that

Comment: see update.. still get an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12

Comment: I updated the code, check again please! It works fine using phpmyadmin, I checked it.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12. see update

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15766/discussion-between-jocelyn-and-dmitry-makovetskiyd)

Answer (score 1):

The real MySQL syntax for IF THEN ELSE is

```
   IF THEN
   ELSEIF THEN
   ELSE
   END IF
```

Actually, you're using `ELSE IF` instead, replace it by `ELSEIF`, and it's going to work

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS shorten;

delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION shorten(s VARCHAR(255), n INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
 BEGIN
 IF ISNULL(s) THEN
 RETURN '';
 ELSEIF n<15 THEN
RETURN LEFT(s, n);
 ELSEIF CHAR_LENGTH(s) <= n THEN
 RETURN s;
 ELSE
 RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(s, n-10), ' ... ', RIGHT(s, 5));
  END IF;

 END$$
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14

Comment: This works on my machine. Running `SELECT shorten("This is a test",3)` I get the expected output: `Thi`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE  FUNCTION shorten(s VARCHAR(255), n INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
IF ISNULL(s) THEN 
RETURN '';
ELSEIF n<15 THEN
RETURN LEFT(s,n);
ELSE 
IF CHAR_LENGTH(s) <= n THEN
RETURN s;
ELSE
RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(s, n-10), '... ',RIGHT(s,5));
END IF;
END IF;
END$$
```

try including one more END IF in ur statement and this should work :)